# Banned from reviewing through a really strange question

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just got banned from review for four days and can not really understand why this happened. The question that kicked me was [Google Maps StackOverflowError crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50881803/google-maps-stackoverflowerror-crashes), and I commented about the lack of context for that question - I didn't flag to close it, but I don't think that it is a good question either. I have no clue how this got eleven upvotes, and I don't think it is fair to get banned in such a unclear situation...

Comment: To be fair, you didn't get banned for failing **this** review. You had to fail other audits previously.

Comment: 11 upvotes on that question are a bit unusual, though. But some tags are quite more generous and forgiving than others.

Comment: Then it should be fair to get a hint about which **other** reviews lead to the ban. Is there any way to get a log of this? IIRC, the other bans before also resulted from unclear situations where I could have handled the review better, but also worse

Comment: And yes, I flagged to close that question ;)

Comment: All the review audits that you failed previously brought you to the ban.

Comment: @yivi The question it links to has a score of 8 and mentions that the issue they're encountering even happens in Lyft and Yelp so I think it's a case of a bunch of people running into this problem.

Comment: rene made a userscript that will allow you to see which posts were audits in your review history: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251508/293308 It also shows whether your review matched the end result for real reviews.

Comment: So, my main question remains: yes, I might have reviewed other stuff wrong (which I would like to learn from more in retrospective, that's why I'm asking about such a list), but I still stay banned even if the question itself is not a good one?

Comment: @NicoHaase Lifting your ban is up to a diamond moderator. Still, it's only a four day long ban, with the weekend coming up. Might be a good opportunity to think about taking review slower and more carefully. Some times you'll need to open the open the post outside of the review queue to take a deeper look, for example. Or to skip more often. I wouldn't make a big deal out of it, personally. But maybe a moderator thinks that lifting your review ban is warranted.

Comment: I find the term "ban" a really sad one anyway. You're being throttled, not punished. Temporary break is more like it.

Comment: A break is fine, yes, and I don't want to get excempted through being a nag. But if the "ban" or break happened on a unfair basis, I'd like to put this under question. Is it fair to put people who would like to help the community under a ban that fast? And even if I will check what I've done wrong in the past, I don't remember failing that many tests or being too sloppy.....

Comment: @Nico that's not the greatest of audits and the last audit failure you had was a bit iffy as well. I've lifted your review ban.