# Review suspension for an incorrectly rejected edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review-suspension

I have to ask for a strange review suspension once again: this time, it is indicated that I reviewed https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20430133 incorrectly. I don't see what in there could be wrong, as another reviewer also rejected that edit and currently, I cannot even see what that edit was all about, as the edit comment is very unclear and the diff view shows only identical lines and even no edited tags.

As there were questions about whether I properly checked for which review I was suspended:

> You reviewed https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20430133
>   incorrectly.
>  Please pay more attention to each review in the
>   future.
>
> Come back in 2 days to continue reviewing.

Just in my [last question about this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370546/banned-from-reviewing-through-a-really-strange-question), I don't want to get unsuspended through whining, but I'd like to see what exactly went wrong in that review to learn from it.

Comment: both source are exactly the same : https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25d236bf-25f2-489d-904b-f8d07399db16/view-source | https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1937f893-51a8-4d4c-a45c-cb72c24baf9b/view-source

Comment: It says something about sensitive naming. Maybe it was redacted for protection of privacy or similar?

Comment: Since that post isn't an audit, I guess this was a manual suspension enacted by a mod?

Comment: It does look like the post history was manipulated. That and being suspended by a non-audit review seem to clearly indicate a mod was involved. If this is the case, only a diamond moderator can tell us the rest of the details.

Comment: The same user made an edit on another post with the exact same edit summary as the version of the edit on this post that got approved by a mod: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20427863  You can see the diff in this version but it's not clear to me why the change was important.

Comment: The OP accidentally exposed his company name and tried to correct it.  Multiple times, a mod got involved.  You were not lucky with the mod, it is not a moderate one.  I'd assume that history was changed, but imperfectly, the company name is still visible in the question edit history.  Mistakes compounding mistakes.

Comment: OK, just realized the OP of both questions and the editor are the same user. Now this makes sense. This could have been avoided with a good edit summary that actually explained that the OP didn't want their company name referenced in the code.

Comment: And after all, I was suspended from review for which reason?

Comment: Because you prevented sensitive information from being removed @NicoHaase. In hindsight, the edit message was clear, yet you did decide to prevent it. As for your claim `"as far as I remember that edit, it contained editing it from SampleApplication to that sensitive name, and that's why I rejected it."` it's been disproven by a community manager. Paying attention to these kind of details is important. (It also makes no sense, how would you have known what sensitive means for OP?)

Comment: Editing a question does not remove the company name. It just buries the company name in the revision history. The only way to get redact is to flag, in which case the end result is exactly the same regardless of whether the edit was accepted or rejected. We are encouraged to reject edits that don't significantly improve a question, so in my opinion NicoHaase was correct to reject.

Comment: @Rainbolt the correct course of action is the edit it out and flag for a moderator as described here https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132119/381239 editing it out does bury it, which is the aim because it reduces the chances of new people seeing it before a moderator can redact it

Comment: @Rainbolt "We are encouraged to reject edits that don't significantly improve a question" [citation needed]!

Comment: @Braiam I was wrong. I learned that the rejection reason I had in mind was [removed some time ago, and replaced with a new one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239106/254466).

Comment: @Rainbolt no, it wasn't replaced. "**This is not a replacement for "too minor"**, but it does replace one of the things folks were using it for: edits that don't make any **positive changes** to the post."

Comment: @Braiam I respect your and shog9's opinion, but to me it looks like a replacement.

Comment: @Rainbolt well, the guy is one that controls the content on SE, so I say is much more than a mere "opinion".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note the review history is now altered, as the post was redacted, so we cannot see the original review. It essentially replaced:

"sensitive Name" -> "sampleApplication"

The question had been edited prior to the review and the editor put in the review comment:

> Removing reference to sensitive naming

To me this is clear that they're renaming the classes to be generic and not expose sensitive information.

The editor had attempted to [edit the post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20427857)*, twice and both times it was rejected. The user got a resulting suggested edit ban and needed to raise a mod flag to have get the edit. This was helpful, as the user didn't understand redaction.

However, on the review side of things, I review banned all of you who rejected it (that didn't automatically incur a ban) so you'd pay attention to the suggested edits. That was all. If I hadn't banned you, you wouldn't have noticed. Don't consider it a punishment, but more a tap on the shoulder to say "hey can you please pay more attention".

*Note that edit rejection was reversed, which caused an automatic ban of at least one of those reviewers.

p.s. I'll unban you as clearly, you're listening. Thanks.

Comment: Also: Wouldn't it be more useful to issue a warning by sending said users a mod message, instead of inflicting a punishment?

Comment: @FrankerZ yes it would be, but believe it or not a mod warning is more serious than a review ban. (I didn't create the system). There's no other way, other than leaving a comment under one of the user's posts or dragging them into a chatroom. The ban is as effective as anything. Those who want to improve, ask why.

Comment: Well, then I don't get it: as far as I remember the edit I should review, it was to replace `SampleApplication` with something unreadable. And that's why I rejected that edit. So, even if I clearly get the point of "tapping on the shoulder for being more attentive", I don't get how those rejecting a strange edit need that?

Comment: @YvetteColomb And what happens if the users don't review for 2 days. They wont see anything, right? Perhaps it's time to post a feedback for simple messages to send to users, without issuing actual warnings.

Comment: @NicoHaase No, the review has changed, as the post has been redacted. At the time you reviewed it: "sensitiveName" -> "sampleApplication" It was pretty clear.

Comment: @FrankerZ Yeh, that would be a feature request. Not sure if it will fly. People respond different to censure, and some people want to improve and others do not.

Comment: I'd rather be dragged in  a chatroom. Not because of the message I'll get there, I like the dragging ...

Comment: @NicoHaase The question/answer included a reference to a project that shouldn't be on Stack Overflow, let's call it `ProjectXApplication`. The OP then noticed this, and edited the question and the answer (`ProjectXApplication` → `SampleApplication`) with a message explaining that the classname was edited to redact the sensitive name (which is the proper way of handling this, as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132119)). Considering that the edit message was self-explanatory and the question was edited beforehand, this would be a valid edit, so it shouldn't have been rejected.

Comment: ....still, as far as I remember that edit, it contained editing it **from** `SampleApplication` to that sensitive name, and that's why I rejected it. How can everybody else be so sure about what I have seen on my screen?

Comment: @NicoHaase I've asked one of the CM to check it, and I remember seeing it, which is why I banned you. But don't take my word for it.

Comment: @NicoHaase How can the user who suggest the edit know the OP's sensitive information‽ ...

Comment: @user202729 because it was the OP of the question who made the edit

Comment: @YvetteColomb (sorry, mistake, comment edited) Still, if OP edit the question then it should not be a review, right?

Comment: @NicoHaase I verified with a community manager and what I said I saw is correct and you are misremembering it. As for all the carry on and downvotes, you've had 9 review bans, so people can hardly call me out for handing one out. Next time I won't be lifting it in a hurry, as it's clear you haven't learnt a thing, you're still arguing about it

Comment: @user202729 the OP edited the answer to their question. It's up to the reviewer to investigate that. If they're unsure they can check the question - or - skip

Comment: @YvetteColomb What consequences may a mod warning return in?

Comment: @user202729 an official mod warning is a private message from the moderators to the user. They're taken seriously, by us anyway. It stays on the record and may count at some point to the user being suspended.

Comment: Given that the community (somehow?) disagree with this and agree with [the comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371711/review-suspension-for-an-incorrectly-rejected-edit?noredirect=1#comment615076_371716), someone should probably make a feature-request for "soft moderator warning".

Comment: I don't understand all the pushback here. OP did a bad review, was banned, I'm happy that at least some people are trying to get reviewers to become better...

Comment: @user202729 It's hard to tell if the community really disagrees, it's mostly "votes in the dark". As far as new development happens (op being banned 9 times already (nine. they have the right to review since like, three months), the content not being what they said) we have all indication that Yvette acted correctly. Meta might have taken the habit of dvting Yvette, let's try and stop that.

Comment: Could another moderator/SO staff member who can see the original version of the question comment about how obviously "sensitive name" was problematic and in need of redaction?  If it was just something like "Actual Company Name" or "Professor Smith's CS101 Assignment" I'm not sure if I'd've approved the edit or not.

Comment: @DanNeely well I've asked a CM to post, but I cannot force them. You can either believe me or not that a CM can see the breakdown and I'm telling the truth. It was an identifying name and it was changed to a generic one. There's really not anything else left for me to say about this. It was something relatively simple and I cannot force people to trust me or believe me, that is something that will take time.

Comment: @YvetteColomb  I overlooked your saying you requested one above.  My intent wasn't to pile on to either side of the argument, but to try and get a response from one of the handful of other people with sufficient data access to have an informed opinion about what happened.

Comment: Don't want to be picky, but out of these nine prior bans (which, in most cases, were not questioned), the last one was discussed here as being an edge case that was not intentionally done "wrong" by me and the one before was "iffy" according to Jon Clements. So, after all, I accept being warned, but I think that the concept should rather be based on "I tell you what was wrong, please learn from it" than "Don't argue with a mod, or I will not help you next time"

Comment: @NicoHaase There is a difference between "don't argue with a mod" and "open your ears". We have all latitude to discuss, challenge and ask about decisions. I mean heck, look at all the attention this question got, all the amount of comments! This is nothing close to "don't argue with a mod", don't play the victim card here.

Comment: And even there @Nico, let's say only 7 of these bans were warranted, it still means that **seven times you did not learn from it**. At some point the "please" must stop and a user must feel a real effect. I'd actually say that after 7 times, there are no "please" that are necessary.

Comment: Yes, it's all okay, I **want** to learn from it, and I don't want to be the victim, you're completely right. But it would be cool to get the right tools to the people to learn - what about a list of audits I failed, to keep track for myself what went wrong? On the other side, I was happy to ask about the last audit ban, cause it was only a matter of short time to see that adding a comment on an unclear question got me wrongfully banned. From my point of view, that is not a completely fair way to go - yes, it might be the easiest one for the technics, but not a fair one in all cases

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's how meta works, though. Downvotes don't mean "this is a bad answer", they mean "I disagree". Clearly, people disagree with something in the answer, probably Yvette's logic, and are making their opinions known. The snark is both unhelpful and unnecessary.

Comment: @Nic please don't tell me you believe that. Of course, we say the sempiternal "votes are different on meta", but thats really marketting, people vote for any reason, including this is a bad answer, but also I don't like this, or I don't like this poster, or I lost my keys.

Comment: I suspect that there's some mod-bashing involved too. When a mod "exposes" his/herself like this, no need to lambast him/her (note that the answer was accepted!). Well, I suppose that's human.

Comment: +1 for an accurate and honest accounting of the event.  Though I'm not normally a fan of bolding, you might bold the first sentence *"Note the review history is now altered, as the post was redacted, so we cannot see the original review"* to make it crystal clear for dullards like me that you won't be able to see the sensitive name in the history.  (I checked twice before finally realizing it was redacted).

Comment: The answer was upvoted and accepted by me, as it gives a clear explanation about what happened, and I highly appreciate this discussion!

Comment: @DanNeely I frequently visit the [tag:spring-boot] tag and I've seen the original name. It was a name that I couldn't make anything out of, so I assume it was an undisclosed project. But considering (a) the edit message (b) the edit changing it to a generic name (c) the question had already been edited to use the generic name so it made more sense to change the answer as well (or to rollback both) and (d) that it's recommended to edit the sensitive information first according to [this meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132119), I think I would have approved it.

Comment: @Felix actually I think you are missing the point that many of the DVs on this answer may be exactly because "I disagree" i.e. there may be people other than me who use the correct meta voting pattern. The logic and how this seemed to have played out sounds questionable. The review system in this case flawed. The assumption that -50 votes to Yvette are somehow personal, unfair.

Comment: exactly what I meant: it looks personal to me. next time maybe Yvette won't answer & expose herself because of that.

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm really pleased we're reached an accord. One thing I've learnt from this is to be more understanding and to show it. So we've both learnt and perhaps many readers will learn too :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre kind words, but I'm tough and will answer for my actions. I'm used to conflict on meta. Much of it I brought on myself, and only time will remove that.

Comment: seems like being a mod has a steep leaning curve... hang on :)

Comment: I've never seen a more controversial moderator than this one...every post that has an issue if I click on it and read it I can tell you who the mod was.  Stop being so gun happy.